# QPushButton show/hide based on Mouse over event

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt-creator

I have one question regarding the QPushButton.

i want the QPushButton behaviour in such a way that it should be shown only when the focus is there on QPushButton, and when the focus is out then it should hide. Below is the image that have "View" button, it displayed only when the focus is there on the QPushButton.

[image]

Thanks,
Neel

Answer (score 0):

Subclass QWidget.

Create a QPushButton member.

Override the [QWidget::enterEvent](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qwidget.html#enterEvent) and QWidget::leaveEvent protected methods to show / hide the QPushButton.

Override the [QWidget::resizeEvent](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qwidget.html#resizeEvent) to resize the QPushButton.